# AngularJS - change controller model in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a simple angular example http://codepen.io/snater/pen/mHsAt, what I want is on span click, controllers model changing from directive, and text field taking model's value. Is this possible?

Comment: why dont you use <input ng-model='ngModel' /> in template

Comment: I need to add some more elements to input, with template I see this "Error: Template must have exactly one root element"

Comment: To get past that error, wrap your template in a <div>.

Comment: But then attributes from input move to this div instead new input

Comment: Interesting, that model actualy take new value, but input doesn't know anything about it. Maybe there is method to force view to refresh bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong syntax to refer to ngModel, combined with the fact that probably ngModel is already used by Angular in some other way; if you change the name of the property you use to store the text, i.e. `txtVal`, and refer to it without `scope.`in the template, you should be able to change the value of the input upon clicking on the span.

Something like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="ctrl">

<input change-model txt-val="change_me" />

<p>{{change_me}}</p>
```

And in the js file:

```
app.directive "changeModel", ($compile) ->
  priotity: 0
  restrict: "A"
  scope:
     txtVal: '='
  link: (scope, element, attrs) -> 
     //Use txtVal instead of scope.txtVal here
     tpl = "<input ng-model='txtVal' /><span data-value='Write this to model' ng-click='clickHandle()'>Must paste text on click</span></span>"
    new_el = angular.element(tpl)
    scope.clickHandle = ->
       scope.txtVal = "some text"
```

With these changes, clicking on the span updates both the value of the input and the content of the `<p>`

Comment: Thanks! Looks like name of value doesn't matter, but using no scope solves problem.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't sure about ngModel being somehow reserved by Angular for its own purposes, anyway I still think it's better to change it for clarity's sake.